# Exception error while trying to load nlu pretrained model

Tags: pyspark, nlp, nlu

I am trying to load nlu pretrained model but it throws the below error :

> Exception: Something went wrong during creating the Spark NLP
> model_anno_obj for your request = en.med_ner.diseasesDid you use a NLU
> Spell?

i am able to load `nlu.load('biobert')`, `nlu.load('sentiment')` & such other models but fails for `nlu.load("en.med_ner.diseases")`, `nlu.load('en.med_ner.ade.clinical_bert')` & other such models.

```
! pip install nlu pyspark==3.0.2
import nlu
nlu.load("en.med_ner.diseases").predict("""I feel a bit drowsy & have a little blurred vision """)
```

i referred below notebook but error remained the same :
https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/nlu/blob/master/examples/colab/healthcare/medical_named_entity_recognition/overview_medical_entity_recognizers.ipynb

where i am going wrong..?